# Hardhat: Default value for param of task doesn't match the default one, try specifying it

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to add my own task to the hardhat.
Everything works fine when I use function addParam without specifying the type (by default it uses string). But when I use **addParam with number or addParam with type obj** and run **npx hardhat** I get an error - **Default value for param primitive type of task first-task doesn't match the default one, try specifying it.**

Does hardhat support any other type than string?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try "str: String" instead of "str: string"

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: which version of hardhat are you using? https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/create-task . They don't add the value inside addParam. the value come as input when you call the task :/